# Orthogonal Surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Show that the surfaces $$x^2+y^2+z^2=\alpha x, \space x^2+y^2+z^2=\beta y$$ and $$x^2+y^2+z^2=\gamma z$$ are pairwise orthogonal to each other.

I know that two surface are orthogonal if the normals of the surfaces are perpendicular at a particular point. But I do not know how can I use this technique in this problem or do I have to use some different rule.

Comment: In each of these three cases, the intersection is a curve, check the orthogonality in its points...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: Note that $\alpha x = \beta y$ at a point of intersection of the first two surfaces. Now, $\nabla (x^2+y^2+z^2-\alpha x) = (2x-\alpha,2y,2z)$ and $\nabla(x^2+y^2+z^2-\beta y) = (2x,2y-\beta y,2z)$. At such a point of intersection, what is the dot product of the two gradients?

Comment: As they are supposed to be perpendicular to each other. The dot product should be zero....

Comment: Right. Now just do the calculation (i.e., a little bit of algebra) and see that it is! :)

Comment: $$\nabla(x^2+y^2+z^2-\alpha x)=(2x-\alpha, 2y,2z)----(1)$$
$$\nabla(x^2+y^2+z^2-\beta y)=(2x, 2y-\beta,2z)----(2)$$
$$\nabla(x^2+y^2+z^2-\gamma z)=(2x, 2y,2z-\gamma)----(3)$$
Now taking the dot product of pair of (1) and (3)
$$ (2x-\alpha, 2y,2z)  . (2x, 2y,2z-\gamma)=4(x^2+y^2+z^2)-4z\gamma=4z \gamma -4z \gamma=0$$
so this pair is orthogonal

Is it correct??

Comment: Right, it's the analogous calculation for each of the three pairs. (I guess you already used $\alpha x = \gamma z$ there.)

Comment: Yes I did use that. It is ok to use that condition, right?

Comment: Of course!! It's just that you had skipped a step in your algebra, so I wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Each surface above can be written as $f_j^{-1}(K)$ where $K \in \mathbb{R}$. For the pairwise argument, find a point $p$ in the intersection of two surfaces then calculate the gradients and show that $\nabla f_j(p), \nabla f_i(p)$ are orthogonal at $p$. So yes, your idea is correct, I just think you didn't know how to get the normals for the equations.

Comment: I know how to get normals to the given surfaces. But the point where I am confused is: Will the p be an arbitrary point or do I have to find the intersection of the surfaces? If yes then, I think, the intersection of first pair gives $\alpha x= \gamma z$ and second pair gives $\beta y = \gamma z$. I do not know what I have to do after this.

Comment: @hitman, it's a point for wich the condition for it to be in the intersection is fulfilled. The equations you wrote must be true **too** in the expression for the gradients of the corresponding intersecting surfaces.